# Is there a website to check all media codecs?

Tags: installation, codecs, websites

i've installed ubuntu on the notebook of my sister and want to make sure that all media codecs work, so that she can surf on the internet and download media and everything will work.

with media codecs i mean stuff like:
flash,
mpeg,
avi,
quicktime,
real,
mp3,
wma,
ogg,
m3u,
all kind of stream codecs.

Wondering if there is such a site on the web.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu should be setup so that when a media type is first-played then Ubuntu will guide the user to install the appropriate codecs via the internet (if they are not already installed).  Installing the two `ubuntu-restricted-*` packages from the Ubuntu Software Centre or command-line should be sufficient:

- `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-addons ubuntu-restricted-extras`

I'm sorry that I don't know of a test site with media samples, but perhaps we should set one up to help Ubuntu users?  *(The snippets would have to be legally free/libre before they could be hosted, which is going to be much harder to acquire unless they are encoded specifically for the purpose).*

Comment: Movie trailers and advertisements are free, so are commercials. They can be converted to different formats, and then the user can download a compressed file and test out all different codecs. Although this is going to be easy as there are a lot of different types of codecs.

Comment: **Vitaly:** The problem is that movie and film trailers may be zero-cost *(gratius)*, but that does not mean that the trailer comes with the permission to re-encode, change, or host the files *(free-as-in-freedom: libre)*.  Suitable free content means films such as Sintel (http://www.sintel.org/) that are legal to modify/share/re-encoded and host (licensed as CC-BY-SA or better: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

Comment: Remember to install DVD support with `sudo apt-get install libdvdread4` and `sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`

Comment: @sladen `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` is sufficient, since the other is a dependency of it.

Answer (score 0):

See about:plugins in your web browser.